# SQL Server How to merge rows in group by

Tags: sql

I have the query below which is returning multiple progYear, this started happening when I added in the INFO component type.

Does anyone know how I can merge them so the calculations are grouped properly.

```
SELECT CASE WHEN [Component Type] = 'INFO' 
            THEN 'Heating' 
            ELSE [Component Type] END [Component Type],
       COUNT([PLACE-REF])             Grand_Total,  
       SUM(TotalCost)                 Grand_Total_Cost, 
       ProgYear 
FROM ABP_BUILD.dbo.ABP_AssetsComponentCostSummary 
WHERE Repeating = 1
  AND [Component Type] IN ('Heating','INFO')
  AND [component description] NOT IN (
      'Electric Panel Heaters ',
      'Electric Storage Heaters',
      'Electric Heating',
      'Electric Boiler') 
  AND [component description] NOT IN ('Gas - Boiler')
GROUP BY [Component Type], 
         ProgYear, 
         [component description]
```

This is part of a bigger query that uses a union all so we need to keep the same columns.

Current Output:

| Component Type | Grand_Total | Grand_Total_Cost | ProgYear |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Heating | 49 | 294000 | 2029 |
| Heating | 2 | 5632 | 2030 |
| Heating | 1985 | 5589760 | 2029 |

Expected Output:

| Component Type | Grand_Total | Grand_Total_Cost | ProgYear |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Heating | 2034 | 5883760 | 2029 |
| Heating | 2 | 5632 | 2030 |

Any input appreciated

How can I combine/change INFO to show as HEATING in the AND [Component Type] IN ('Heating','INFO') statement, I believe that would fix it

Comment: I dont understand your question because the query doesnt match the results, but basically if you have 2 queries and you UNION ALL them together, you have to use *that entire thing* as a subquery to groupby a second time. take what you have, wrap the entire thing in parenthesis, and then query that and SUM the Grand_Totals group by Component Type

Comment: The reason why I mentioned it is part of a union all is that I don't want the columns to be amended.

This query output does match the columns.

Comment: How can I combine/change INFO to show as HEATING in the AND [Component Type] IN ('Heating','INFO') statement, I believe that would fix it.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you are trying to aggregate partially on your fields of selection/filtering, you need to use a common table expression/subquery to aggregate successfully on your interested fields.

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT CASE WHEN [Component Type] = 'INFO' 
                THEN 'Heating' 
                ELSE [Component Type] END [Component Type],
           [PLACE-REF],  
           TotalCost, 
           ProgYear 
    FROM ABP_BUILD.dbo.ABP_AssetsComponentCostSummary 
    WHERE Repeating = 1
      AND [Component Type] IN ('Heating','INFO')
      AND [component description] NOT IN (
          'Electric Panel Heaters ',
          'Electric Storage Heaters',
          'Electric Heating',
          'Electric Boiler') 
      AND [component description] NOT IN ('Gas - Boiler')
)
SELECT [Component Type],
       COUNT([PLACE-REF]) AS Grand_Total,  
       SUM(TotalCost)     AS Grand_Total_Cost, 
       ProgYear 
FROM cte
GROUP BY [Component Type], 
         ProgYear
```

Comment: The issue is I can't use that as I am using several union all throughout the query, this is part of another query.

Comment: You can include your whole query inside the cte, and use the content of the current cte inside the part that was missing in your query. Another option is transforming this cte in a subquery: if you need this transformation, I can update the content of this answer. @user3306489